# removing url query string

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have this link: 
http://joa.upcreation.com/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/?plan=1

and i want this :
http://joa.upcreation.com/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/plan

I tried this but doesn't work ...

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ 
 RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

here my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/plan? [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteBase /



AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

SetEnv PHP_VER 5



RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/plan? [NE,R=301,L]
```

#### Full .htaccess:

```
#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1/plan? [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

#### UPDATE:: curl output:

```
curl -k -3 -L -I 'http://joa.upcreation.com/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/?plan=1'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 19:52:52 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://joa.upcreation.com/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/plan
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 19:52:52 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
X-Pingback: http://joa.upcreation.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://joa.upcreation.com/plan-du-site/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 19:52:53 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
X-Pingback: http://joa.upcreation.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://joa.upcreation.com/?p=99>; rel=shortlink
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks ! but this redirects me to another directory : http://joa.upcreation.com/plan-du-site/

Comment: ok try it now, this rule actually should be placed in DocumentRoot/.htaccess not in a sub-dir

Comment: actually it is already in documentRoot, but in my .htaccess i have others rules :

Comment: Hmm in that case make sure above rule is the **first rule** in your .htaccess

Comment: Also as you can see its impossible to read code here. Please post it in your question

Comment: I did that, but this is still not working : Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/plan? [NE,R=301,L]

Comment: Do you have any `.htaccess` in sub directories as well?

Comment: I have provided your full .htaccess in my answer. Also make sure to use a different browser to test it.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, but it still redirects me to " joa.upcreation.com/plan-du-site" maybe a php function can work ?

Comment: Actually I ran your URLs in curl and found that your code/framework is doing an additional 301 redirect which is not controlled by above rules. See **UPDATE** section with the curl's output. You can see my rule works correctly and redirects `http://joa.upcreation.com/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/?plan=1` to `http://joa.upcreation.com/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/plan` but due to an additional 301 redirect  URL becomes `http://joa.upcreation.com/plan-du-site/`

Answer (score 0):

You can have the ***incoming*** URI as `/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/plan`, and use .htaccess to convert it into a form that the server can handle: `/nos-restaurants/cesar-palace/?plan=1`. You **can't** go the other way! You have to *add* the Query String.